# Changing the color of the stroke dynamically in Recyclerview Adapter class

Tags: android, xml

How to change the color of the stroke which is in rectangle in shape? I want to change the color dynamically in top stroke or bottom stroke color of the particular item in RecyclerView Adapter.

@drawable/border_custom

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- TOP STROKE-->
<item android:top="15dp" android:id="@+id/deviceTop">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/ripple_divider" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- BOTTOM STROKE-->
<item android:top="15dp" android:id="@+id/deviceBottom">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/ripple_divider" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!--LEFT STROKE-->
<item android:left="15dp" android:id="@+id/deviceLeft">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/ripple_divider" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!--RIGHT STROKE-->
<item android:right="15dp" android:id="@+id/deviceRight">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/ripple_divider" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- MAIN SHAPE -->
<item android:top="15dp" android:bottom="15dp" android:left="15dp" android:right="15dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/ripple_white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Here is my XML file where I am using above XML in my Linear Layout the background

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llDevice"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_device"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>
```

and my Main Activity XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: did you make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to your Drawable as a LayerDrawable via:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.border_device);
```

And then you can reference your different layers via their id's

```
GradientDrawable leftSide = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.deviceLeft);
```

And lastly modify it's color:

```
leftSide.setColor(Color.GRAY);
```